# Cassandra CQL SELECT results to single JSON

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is it possible to perform a SELECT query in Cassandra DB to get all result fields as one single JSON?

For example, I have table Products:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| UUID |  Name  | Price |
+------+--------+-------+
| 1234 | Potato | 1$    |
| 1235 | Tomato | 2$    |
| .... |  ....  |  ...  |
+------+--------+-------+
```

Can I somehow get a result like this without creating my own function with just one SELECT query?

```
{"uuid": "1234", "uuid": "12345", ...}
```

SELECT JSON won't work, it will return results in not in a single row:

```
{"uuid": "1234"}
{"uuid": "1235"}
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your JSON is incorrect - you can't have two fields with the same name in the JSON object.  I can imaging that it could be `[{"uuid": "1234"}, {"uuid": "1235"}]` if we talk about correct JSON format.

Even if we talk about creating the list of JSON objects, it's not possible to do only via CQL.

If you want to get data from Cassandra for UI, or something else that works with JSON, then you can look to the [Stargate project](https://stargate.io/) that provides REST & GraphQL interface to Cassandra databases.